# /help() function not return docstring of user-defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried using the python help() function to preview the docstring of a function I created but the terminal keeps saying "NameError: name 'functionName' is not defined".

I tried passing parameters into my function but nothing's helped.

```py
def coefficients():
    """ Evaluates value of inputs and determines use case for almighty formula function """
    def coefficient_of_xsquared():
        if a == "" or a == 0 or a == " ":
            print (error)
            return a 
        coefficient_of_xsquared()

    def coefficient_of_x(): 
        if b == "" or b == 0 or b == " ":
            print (error)
            return b
        coefficient_of_x()

    def coefficient_of_one():
        if c == "" or c == 0 or c == " ":
            print (error)
            return c
        coefficient_of_one()
```

Expected: Evaluates value of inputs and determines use case for almighty formula function

Actual:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'coefficients' is not defined
```

Comment: Don't use recursion like this; use a simple `while` loop to repeat an action until a condition is true.

Comment: How are you using `help()` exactly?

Comment: I'm using `help()` to output the docstring of the function I've created above, which is failing in this case @Goyo

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the function isn't defined when you are trying to call `help`.

If the function is defined in a file (e.g. `modulename.py`), you need to import it into the interactive interpreter before you can use it. If the files is called `MODULENAME.py`, use `from MODULENAME import coefficients` before you try to use it.

Comment: I'm using an IDE (VS Code) to update the source code and the function is defined in that same file, so it can't really be imported as it's one file I'm working with

Comment: Make sure the function is defined before you try to call `help`. If it already is, it sounds like it might be a problem with VS Code or with how you're running it. If you run the script directly from a command line, what happens?